# To whom does the Vice President of India submit his resignation?

Tags: india, vice-president

In India, the Vice-President shall submit his resignation to the President. But my question is:

In the absence of the President, the Vice-President shall submit his resignation to____?

Comment: A related question is whether the vice-president becomes the president at the moment the former president is no longer president, or not until the vice-president takes the presidential oath of office. If he or she becomes president immediately, he or she would submit the resignation from the office of president to the [secretary of state](https://www.archives.gov/historical-docs/todays-doc/?dod-date=809).

Comment: VEEP becomes POUTS before the oath is taken, technically speaking.  He did take the Oath of Office at the inauguration ceremony, and the office includes replacement President.   There's also the case of the rare event of an inauguration falling on a Sunday, the swearing in ceremony is done the following Monday, but the President-Elect is President as of noon Sunday.

Comment: @hszmv the vice presidential oath is different from the presidential oath, and a new president is constitutionally prohibited from "entering on the execution of his office" until after he takes the presidential oath.  Since 1877 there has been the practice of having a private oath on Sunday and a public ceremony on Monday, but this has only happened twice for a president's first term: Taylor in 1849 and Hayes in 1877.  There does not seem to be an actual need for a second-term president to swear the oath.

Answer (score 3):

[In the US](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/20), the resignation of the office of President or Vice-President must be in writing to the Secretary of State. In India, [the constitution](https://www.india.gov.in/sites/upload_files/npi/files/coi_part_full.pdf) provides (Art. 65) that

> In the event of the occurrence of any vacancy in  the  office  of 
>   the  President  by  reason  of  his  death, resignation  or  removal, 
>   or  otherwise,  the  Vice-President shall  act  as  President  until 
>   the  date  on  which  a  new President  elected  in  accordance  with 
>   the  provisions  of this  Chapter  to  fill  such  vacancy  enters 
>   upon  his  office

and (Art 67)

> a Vice-President may, by writing under his hand addressed  to  the 
>   President,  resign  his  office;

It does not require that the president be named, nor does it require that the resignation actually be delivered to the president. The VP a.k.a. acting President can notify himself of his resignation, since he functions completely as the president. The houses of parliament might elect a new vice president between resignations.

Comment: Great answer but I don't think this is correct answer as per India Government